.Net6 how to open pdf after returning it as a file and download
I generate a pdf in my controller and return it as a file.It downloads it but what i want is i want to open it automatically after download but not in browser, i want it to be opened in whatever the default pdf viewer of user is, like it can be adobe etc...
This is my code:
                byte[] fileBytes = fileStream.ToArray();
                Response.Headers["Content-Disposition"] = "inline;filename=" + fileName; 
                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                return File(fileBytes, "application/pdf",fileName);

i tried "attachment" instead of "inline" but nothing changed it just downloads the pdf.

The behavior of opening a file automatically in the default PDF viewer after download is determined by the user's browser settings and OS configuration.

@FolabiAhn what settings should be done

On chrome navigator by ex : Settings > Site settings > PDF Documents and toggle the option Open PDFs in Chrome.
Depending on your OS, Ensure that the default PDF viewer is set correctly in the user's settings.

If you want to make the user download and automatic open the file, then that's not possible (it would be very easy to send and execute viruses).

You are right, what if I want to open it in browser, this should be legal tho.
